# Triggers in Mysql 4

Tags: mysql

I have an embedded system which runs mysql 4. It reads RFID cards and stores each reading as an event in a table.
I have to filter out some kind of RFID cards from the table. They are not supposed to appear in the table at any moment. There´s no possibility of modifying the source code of the embeddedd app.

I thought of simply adding a trigger when there´s an insert in the table, to check if the RFID card meets the condition, and then delete it if its needed.
Turns out that triggers appeared in mysql 5 so I'm stuck with my MySql 4.

How can I achieve something similar to a trigger using MySql 4? If there´s no chance, How can I keep the table clean from those RFID cards?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Question edited, thanks.

Comment: This is a bit vague, but your likely limited to running DELETE statements on this table periodically.  Or if you know exactly which cards you do want to allow, could you add them to another table and add a foreign key constraint?

Comment: I cant run delete statements peridocally because I need to keep the table ALWAYS clean. I think I cant use the foreign key idea because, to be more specific, I need to keep out of the table all cards which have 9 chars. The "clean" cards have exactly 10 chars, those are the ones I have to keep.